# How to return bytes to C#/.net from C?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, pinvoke, dllimport

Here's my C function:

```
 DLL_PUBLIC void alve_ripemd320__finish(void* instance, uint32_t* out_hash)
 {
      ...
     for (uint32_t i=0, i_end=10; i<i_end; i++)
     {
         out_hash[i] = h[i]; 
     }
 }
```

and here is how I'm calling it from C#:

```
 [DllImport(PlatformConstants.DllName)]
 static extern void alve_ripemd320__finish (IntPtr instance_space, ref byte[] hash);

 ...

 public byte[] Finish()
 {
     byte[] result = new byte[40];
     alve_ripemd320__finish (c_instance, ref result);
     return result;
 }
```

and that produces an ugly SEGFAULT, which goes away if I comment the C-code above that writes to out_hash.... My question is, is this the correct way of passing a buffer of bytes using PInvoke?

Comment: Gotta ask the obvious:  Does `alve_ripemd320__finish` work when you call it from C?

Comment: @AustinSalonen I never call it from C, but it works (without doing what's intended to) when I comment the code that modifies out_hash. The error can be anywhere else, I know, but mine is a yes/no question: is this the correct way of passing a buffer of bytes using PInvoke?

Comment: Why are you defining the C# side as `byte[]`, when the C API is unsigned integers?

Comment: @ReedCopsey The problem language maps to 320 bits, 10 dwords, or 40 bytes, depending on where you take it. Arguably, for tidiness sake one should use only one of those when coding, I agree...I haven't been thinking too much lately on endiannes, I admit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C API is writing unsigned integers.  I would typically expect this to be mapped as:

```
[DllImport(PlatformConstants.DllName, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void alve_ripemd320__finish(IntPtr instance_space, uint[] hash);

public uint[] Finish()
{
   uint[] result = new uint[10];
   alve_ripemd320__finish (c_instance, ref result);
   return result;
}
```

There are three main changes here:

1. I switched the calling convention to `Cdecl`.  This is the standard for the C++ compiler (unless you're explicitly switching to `stdcall` in `DLL_PUBLIC`).
2. I changed to match your C API, which uses 32 bit unsigned integers instead of bytes.  You should be able to switch back to `byte[]` if you choose, however.
3. You shouldn't need to pass by `ref`.  This would typically be the equivelent of a C API accepting `uint32_t** out_hash`, not `uint32_t* out_hash`, which should map to an array directly.